# Python 3 runing script from one user works but from the other doesn't?

Tags: jenkins, python-3.4

When i run this script from user jenkins (Linux Mint) i get this error, and when running it from my user it works. Jenkins user is created with jenkins service. I have installed virtualenv.

import unittest

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

DRIVER = None

def getOrCreateWebdriver():
    global DRIVER
    DRIVER = DRIVER or webdriver.Firefox()
    return DRIVER


class LoginTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.browser = getOrCreateWebdriver()

    def test_Loggin(self):pass
         browser = self.browser

    def tearDown(self):
        self.browser.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main(verbosity=2)

From user jenkins when i run this script i get error :
test_Loggin (__main__.LoginTest) ... ERROR
/usr/lib/python3.4/unittest/case.py:602: ResourceWarning: unclosed file <_io.BufferedWriter name='/dev/null'>
  outcome.errors.clear()

======================================================================
ERROR: test_Loggin (__main__.LoginTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Test.py", line 16, in setUp
    self.browser = getOrCreateWebdriver()
  File "Test.py", line 10, in getOrCreateWebdriver
    DRIVER = DRIVER or webdriver.Firefox()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 64, in __init__
    self.binary, timeout),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/extension_connection.py", line 51, in __init__
    self.binary.launch_browser(self.profile)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/firefox_binary.py", line 70, in launch_browser
    self._wait_until_connectable()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/firefox_binary.py", line 100, in _wait_until_connectable
    raise WebDriverException("The browser appears to have exited "
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: The browser appears to have exited before we could connect. If you specified a log_file in the FirefoxBinary constructor, check it for details.
```

Comment: I found that when i logged in with jenkis user i cannot run firefox. Error : (process:5773): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion 'sys_page_size == 0' failed
No protocol specified
No protocol specified
Error: cannot open display: :0

Answer (score 0):

When you're logged in as yourself, you need to do `echo $DISPLAY` and note the display info it prints. Subsequently when you login as jenkins service you need to do `xhost +`, `DISPLAY=[display-info]; export DISPLAY`. (display-info is what you got from echo $DISPLAY, ignore the square brackets, they shouldn't be specified in the command)

Hopefully this should work. I don't have similar env to test, just mentioning what i recollect having done it quite sometime back.